# Force Client Side Model Validation MVC 4 (Issue) on type="Button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here's the structure.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id="AddressPartialViewForm", @class="form-horizontal" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-body pal">
        <h3></h3>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserAddressId)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputStates" class="col-md-3 control-label">Address Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title,new{@class="form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="SaveAndNewPartial"  class="btn btn-primary" >Save and New</button>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SaveAndNewPartial").click(function () {
            $.ajax({ .... });
            });
         });
    });
</script>
```

Ok Here is my problem i want the button/form to validate the model before POSTING the model.I know because i am using my own function and type="button" its not performing the validation.

Is there any method to force the form to validate the model in my function? or is there any solution? I want to submit the form using AJAX/JSON technique :)

Comment: No (although you can if you want to)